# Show count value 0 when row doesn't exist MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have 2 tables Game and Bet. I want to count the number of bets for each game. However my current query doesn't include a game when there is no bet for that specific game id.

here is my current query:

```
SELECT g.*, 
       Count(*) AS participants 
FROM   game g, 
       bet b 
WHERE  b.game_id = g.id 
       AND USER = ? 
GROUP  BY g.id
```

So to make it more clear lets say I have 3 rows in my Game table. There are 4 bets for game1 , 2 bets for game2 and there is no row associated with game3 in Bet table. The result should be:

```
g1  4
g2  2
g3  0
```

I'd appreciated any help.

Comment: You need `Outer Join` instead of `Inner join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a left join and count a column that exists in the bet table. For game records that fail to join to the bet table, a single row will be returned in the pre-grouped result-set that will have null in all columns of the bet table. Because the `count()` aggregate function does not count null values, you will get a zero for game records which fail to join.

```
select g.*, count(b.game_id) participants
from game g left join bet b on b.game_id=g.id
where user=?
group by g.id
```

Comment: i think it is a bad practice to select all columns and group by only one of them..even though mysql allows you to do so..

Comment: this worked! so all I had to do instead of normal join was left join!?

Comment: @vkp yes I just wanted to keep the question short. Thanks for the reminder though

Comment: @vkp 1. That comment would be more appropriate on the question, rather than my answer. 2. I completely disagree, I think the idiom of grouping by a unique key and then selecting whatever you want from the key-grouped table is very intuitive and reasonable.

Comment: @HiradRoshandel Yes, it is possible to effectively implement the same logic used by `count()` with the following: `sum(case when b.game_id is null then 0 else 1 end)`.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT g.*,b.count(game_id) as participants FROM game g LEFT join bet b on b.game_id=g.id and user=? group by g.id;

```
Example

mysql> SELECT * FROM calls;
+----+------------+---------+
| id | date       | user_id |
+----+------------+---------+
|  1 | 2016-06-22 |       1 |
|  2 | 2016-06-22 |    NULL |
|  3 | 2016-06-22 |    NULL |
|  4 | 2016-06-23 |       2 |
|  5 | 2016-06-23 |       1 |
|  6 | 2016-06-23 |       1 |
|  7 | 2016-06-23 |    NULL |
+----+------------+---------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM payments;
+----+------------+---------+-------+
| id | date       | user_id | value |
+----+------------+---------+-------+
|  1 | 2016-06-22 |       1 |    10 |
|  2 | 2016-06-22 |       3 |    15 |
|  3 | 2016-06-22 |       4 |    20 |
|  4 | 2016-06-23 |       2 |   100 |
|  5 | 2016-06-23 |       1 |   150 |
+----+------------+---------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT c.*,count(p.user_id) FROM calls c LEFT JOIN payments p ON p.user_id=c.user_id GROUP BY c.user_id;
+----+------------+---------+------------------+
| id | date       | user_id | count(p.user_id) |
+----+------------+---------+------------------+
|  2 | 2016-06-22 |    NULL |                0 |
|  1 | 2016-06-22 |       1 |                6 |
|  4 | 2016-06-23 |       2 |                1 |
+----+------------+---------+------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```